# I cannot change the wlan0 mode. Why?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, ralink

--ralink rt3290, ubuntu 12.04, hp pavilion-g4 laptop--

I'm using my university's wifi.I tried to change the wlan0 mode from "Managed" to "Monitor" mode. But I got an error message:

`Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.`

What's my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable your Network and then Open your terminal and type this command to change mode of `wlan0` to Monitor Mode.

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode Monitor
```

hope that helps.